# Write batch file to delete all but latest X files of each type

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file which should be run once a day, which is supposed to delete all backup files other than the latest, lets say 2 of each type. So I am having files such as:

- backup-DAILY-2018-11-13_000000.bak
- backup-DAILY-2018-11-12_000000.bak
- backup-DAILY-2018-11-11_000000.bak
- backup-HOURLY-2018-11-13_110000.bak
- backup-HOURLY-2018-11-13_130000.bak
- backup-HOURLY-2018-11-13_150000.bak

etc.

So my script looks as follows currently

```
@ECHO off

SET frequency=%*
for %%x in (%frequency%) do (
  for /f "*-%%x*" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /o-d^|more +2') do echo @file
)
```

but I am getting the error `*-%x*" was unexpected at this time.`

What the script should achieve is that once it is run each day I should have the latest 2 backup files of each type(DAILY, HOURLY). Right now I am just trying to print the files that need to be kept.

So what I should be left with is

- backup-DAILY-2018-11-13_000000.bak
- backup-DAILY-2018-11-12_000000.bak
- backup-HOURLY-2018-11-13_130000.bak
- backup-HOURLY-2018-11-13_150000.bak

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding quite a few things here...

Comment: The only fault I see is that you misplaced the `"*-%%x*"` it now looks like a `for /r`. Put it into the dir command. And I'd favor the `"skip=2"` over the `more +2` as the latter is another .exe to load versus the internal for command.

Comment: After `for /F` (and also after `for /R`) you cannot use a meta-variable like `%%x` (neither can you use delayed expansion there), only normal `%`-variables work here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what it is you are trying to achieve with the frequency, but nevertheless, I will focus on what you actualy want to achieve:

```
for /F "skip=2 eol=: delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /o-d *DAILY*') do echo "%%i"
for /F "skip=2 eol=: delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /o-d *HOURLY*') do echo "%%i"
```

So what happens is, we sort by date in reverse order, we then skip the first 2 files (being latest) and delete the rest, we just run 2 seperate loops for each type, hourly and daily. It can be incorporated into a single for loop, but I think this is simple enough.

Obviously replace `echo` with `del` once you confirm it does what you want..

Comment: Thanks a lot this seems to work, I will run it a few times to make sure and of course replace the `echo` with `del`. I am a newbi in scripting, so I think I was pretty confused with how it all was working together. Like that the `dir` command is executed first and then the rest upon the results from that, and I could not find what `/b /o-d` meant, I was looking in the documentation for the `for` cmd whereas I should have looked in the documentation for the `dir` cmd instead. But it is more clear for me now so thank a lot.

Comment: No problems, just shout if you need help.